# How painting works in MONO [Cairo]

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

Question is like How the painting works in MONO CAIRO C#?

In my application I am building an House and design is like i have a lists for every part of the house like one list for roof, one list for wall, one list for basement.. once all the lists are ready then I am printing the lists.

This is the function i will be calling to draw the house

```
public void DrawHouse (Context ct)
{
    house.HouseDrawing.DrawBasement(ct);
    house.HouseDrawing.DrwaWall(ct);
    house.HouseDrawing.DrawRoof(ct);
    house.HouseDrawing.DrawWindows(ct);
    house.HouseDrawing.DrawDoor(ct);
}
```

as of my knowledge Till the lase statement execute nothing should show up on the UI. But the in my case it is printing as soon as the statement executes.

Please let me know how is it working.

Comment: Note on asking questions: Please don't add "thank you notes" to your question (comment, upvote/accept good answers instead) and signature (already in your user name) as they usually add no useful information to the question. And don't normally copy tags into title, especially common once like C#.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is the expected behaviour imo. I'm not sure what house.HouseDrawing.DrawBasement does but I presume it draws to the screen. If that is the case whatever you are drawing will appear when those statements are executed. That drawing will not be permanent on the screen and will need to be redrawn if that part of the screen is invalidated for any reason (eg minimise window, move another window around etc).

Comment: Yes, house.**HouseDrawing.DrawBasement** will draw a basement rectangle on the screen. but my question is when we execute a program sequentially(only one thread), once the control enters to the above function it is not suppose to be responsive till it finishes all the statements in the function. But in my case it is printing the basement once it executes **house.HouseDrawing.DrawBasement** and then its printing  Wall once it executes house.**HouseDrawing.DrwaWall(ct)**.

Comment: But as of my knowledge it should not print any thing till it competes all the statements in the above mentioned method. please correct me if i am wrong also provide me if there is any documents online.

Comment: @Veeresh I have not used mono but if it works like any other drawing functions I have used then it will draw as the commands are executed. There is nothing in your function to tell it to hold off drawing until the last statement is executed. How would it know that you want everything drawn at once? Also, why does it matter?